# Processing JSON from REST call in Ansible

Tags: json, rest, ansible

I'm calling a REST API and try to recombine selected fields of the returned JSON to use it a PUT request, but fail because of my lack of experience with ansible and python ...

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - uri:
        url: "https://test.com/info?comp=COMP1"
        return_content: yes
      register: response1

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ response1.json | to_nice_json }}"

    - set_fact:
        modified_properties: " " # json_query 'magic' ??
    # loop or with_items 'magic' ??

    - uri:
        method: PUT
        url: "https://test.com/put"
        body_format: json
        body: '{"properties": "{{modified_properties}}" }'
```

`response1.json` looks like:

```
{
    "id": "1", 
    "role": {
        "id": "2", 
        "props": [
            {
                "id": "1", 
                "name": "TestName1", 
                "value": "TestVal1"
            }, 
            {
                "id": "2", 
                "name": "TestName2", 
                "value": "TestVal2"
            }, 
            {
                "id": "3", 
                "name": "TestName3", 
                "value": "TestVal3"
            }
        ], 
        "type": "some_type"
    }, 
    "user": "testuser"
}
```

The `modified_properties` need to be like this for the PUT request:

```
{"TestName1":"TestVal1","TestName2":"TestVal2","TestName3":"TestVal3"}
```

I tried the following:

```
    - set_fact:
        modified_properties: '"{{item.name}}": "{{item.value}}"'
      with_list: "{{ response1.json.role.props }}
```

but this only saves the last pair in `modified_properties`:

```
"TestName3": "TestVal3"
```

I tried to extend the `set_fact` with `combine` or `union`, but couldn't figure out how ...

Any help appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!
I'm sure I saw that question earlier already, but couldn't get it working ;-)

Comment: - set_fact: 
    modified_properties: "{{ modified_properties | default({}) | combine( {item.name: item.value} ) }}"
 with_list: "{{ response1.json.role.props }}"

was the solution I choose.